# CSS link (Basic help)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am really struggling to use css to make a new homepage for my smugmug website.

I've managed to get this done:

```
<html style="height:100%">
<body style="height:100%;margin:0;">
<table style="height:100%;width:100%;vertical-align:middle">
<tr>
<td>
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center">
<span style="display:inline-block">WEDDINGS</span><span style="display:inline-block;padding:0 100px">PORTAITS</span><span style="display:inline-block">COMMERCIAL</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and  I want to be able to add a link to each word selection. I can't get my head around it, could anyone please help?

Also if anyone is familiar with smugmug, I paste the code into the theme css box and nothing happens when updating my website.

Thank you.

Comment: In HTML, links are generally created like `<a href="http://example.com">Link Text</a>`. What went wrong with your attempt?

Comment: I have made a link like that, but I'm unsure of where to insert the link.

<p><a href="http://www.websitegoeshere.co.uk/Portrait-Portfolio/.com">Portraits</a></p>

Comment: Your code is HTML code. Did I understand right that you tried to put it in a CSS section? Try placing it in a HTML section, whatever that is in smugmug.

Comment: I would replace the `<span>` elements with `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to add a link around the following line:

```
<span style="display:inline-block">WEDDINGS</span>
```

place the link tag in front and after it, link tag being

```
<a href="LINK TO WEBSITE OR PAGE HERE"> </a>
```

so it would look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com"><span style="display:inline-block">WEDDINGS</span></a>
```

If clicked on, anything between the tag will redirect them to the page.

As a side note, if you wish to make the linked page open in a new tab, use "target=_blank", like this:

```
<a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com" target="_blank"> </a>
```

Comment: I added that code with succsess to the one part, I assume I just adapt it to it will worth with the rest of the options? One more thing.. How do I eliminate the blue "hyperlink" look of the link and keep it grey/black? I did come across "text-decoration: none;" that would work, right?

Comment: @user342355 correct. Text-decoration: none under the class of your link. or in-line within your <a> tag

Comment: @user342355 text-decoration:none will remove the underline from your link. the color will have to be changed manually with color:desiredcolor.

Comment: I will play about with that now.
One final question, I've basically added the links, and they work, although the individual words have all lost their spaces and initial size.

I really appreciate your help Tristan

Comment: are you using css by chance?  As for the spaces, regardless of if you're using just html or both html and css, if you add a space in between the tag and the word, like so:                            <a href="http://google.com"> google </a>  it will space the characters.

Comment: It works, my bad. Not 100% sure where to put the text-decoration and the colour part in my code. :(

Comment: Check out this page, I'm not sure where you are at or what your code looks like. If this doesn't help then feel free to inquire further.  It's a bit hard to guess whats happening on your page without seeing it.  I don't have the most experience either, no worries! Just decided to read some tutorials one day a while back and started making practice pages. Try here: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_link.asp

Comment: if you are using css, in the css document declare: a{ text-decoration:none; color: blue;}  or whatever color

Comment: @user342355
You can use the css scripts  ` a:link { color:#666666; }` (you can change the value of the color.